# Capture full top COMMAND field for short lived process

Tags: linux

I need to capture full process names in the `COMMAND` field of command `top`. My interested process only lived for 2-5 seconds.  I tried something like:
    `top -c | grep`, however, it just didn't work. Any suggestions?

Below is an example line of `COMMAND` field output by `top -c`:

`pdflatex /results/analysis/output/Home/20180612-3_116/report.tex -output-directory /results/analysis/output/Home/20180612-3_116 -interaction+`

contents after -intercation+ are truncated due to screen width limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it, use `pgrep` with the `-a` option. (You'll probably find `pgrep` is in the `procps` package if you don't have it installed.) `-a` tells `pgrep` to print the arguments; by default, it just prints the PID.

```
pgrep -a pdflatext
```

You can also do this with `ps`, which has a lot more options for what it will output:

```
ps -C pdflatex -opid=,cmd= --width=400
```

The above produces the same output as the `pgrep` command (except that it's truncated to 400 characters; I trust that it is obvious how to change that.) If you don't want the PID, leave `pid=,` out of the `-o` option. See `man ps` for the many many other possible options.

Note that Linux only makes the first 4096 bytes of the command line available; there's no way of getting an untruncated command-line if it is longer than that.

Comment: Awesome! Both solutions work on my Ubuntu Linux.